# COUNTING mysql table rows based on 2 conditions from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`. `table1` has columns `id` and `table2_id` while `table2` has `id` and `category`. I need to count rows from `table1` based on two separate values in `table2.category` containing value `Regular` or `Special`.

I have done this in two queries but I want to know if it is possible in a single sql. My queries are:

```
"SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS regular FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id WHERE t2.category = 'Regular'";
"SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS special FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = pr.id WHERE t2.category = 'Special'";
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The second query JOIN should read `ON t1.t2_id = t2.id` and not `ON t1.t2_id = pr.id`. Sorry for the confusion that may have caused. Please update/edit your answers/comments accordingly.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same. Please check your tags.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh! thanks. I can't explain how I could miss that. I have removed the unrelated tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `Where` condition to `CASE` statement and do the counting

Here is one way using `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT
COUNT(case when t2.category = 'Regular' then t1.id end) AS Regular,
COUNT(case when t2.category = 'Special' then t1.id end) AS special 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = pr.id 
Where t2.category IN ('Regular','Special' )
```

**Note :** I have changed the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` because you want to count only when `table2.category`  is `'Regular'` or `'Special'` so no use of `LEFT JOIN` here

Comment: Merely looking at your solution, it feels like the right method, one single row for both counts. I will come back to accept immediately I try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
"SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS regular FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id WHERE t2.category = 'Regular'";
"SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS special FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = pr.id WHERE t2.category = 'Special'";
```

you can do this:

```
select t2.category, count(t1.id)
from table1 t1
left outer join table2
on t1.t2_id = t2.id
group by t2.category
having t2.category in ('Regular', 'Special')
```

The suggested query groups the joined records, filters the groups and selects the category name and its count.

Comment: So how do I pull out the counted values? I guess this solution will result in two separate rows.

Comment: @StephenAdelakun, yes, this results in two separate rows. The need for a single row was not specified in the question, but you can use case when for this purpose as Prdp did in his answer.